# How to use -javaagent in SupervisorD

Tags: supervisord

I'm trying to run Supervisord from Docker, but having trouble for running Java with -javaagent parameter. It gives below error

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/apps/executor.jar
```

It works otherwise if I simply omit -javaagent.

I've tried with below option, but still same error

```
"-javaagent:/usr/apps/executor.jar" 
-javaagent:"/usr/apps/executor.jar"
```

// Supervisor.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
user = root
loglevel = debug

[program:helloworld]
user = root
directory = /usr/apps
# this one will work
# command = /usr/bin/env java -jar /usr/apps/HelloWorld.jar 
# this one will NOT work
command = /usr/bin/env java -javaagent:"/usr/apps/executor.jar" -jar /usr/apps/HelloWorld.jar
# this one will NOT work
#command = /usr/bin/env java "-javaagent:/usr/apps/executor.jar" -jar /usr/apps/HelloWorld.jar
# this one will NOT work
#command = /usr/bin/env java -javaagent:/usr/apps/executor.jar -jar /usr/apps/HelloWorld.jar
```

// DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:11
USER root
COPY ./HelloWorld.jar /usr/apps/HelloWorld.jar
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord","-n"]
```

Appreciate any help to get this to work...

Comment: Your first error message talks about `dd-java-agent.jar`, the examples have `/usr/apps/executor.jar`. Which one is it? Is it actually available in the container?

Comment: sorry, while posting the question, I renamed that part, but didnt rename all... updated the question

Comment: Okay. You're not showing where you'd add `/usr/apps/executor.jar` into the docker container. Should it be in `openjdk:11` already? If not, you'll need to `COPY` it in.

Comment: I didnt have the COPY for that. Let me try it out later, if it fix the issue, I will update here and will gladly accept it as answer.

Comment: @AKX, the file was missing as you mentioned, once I added it, it work. Previously, I'm using different image with that command. I didnt realize that the other image has that file while this image hasnt! Thanks for noticing it, if you will put it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Done :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments.)

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/apps/executor.jar

would imply that the file isn't in the container, so it can't be read. (This can be verified with e.g. `docker build -t myimage .` and `docker run -it --rm myimage ls -la /usr/apps`; if `executor.jar` isn't there, it's... not there.)

You'll need to make sure the file truly is in there with an `ADD` or `COPY` command.